# How to run X86 NASM on Macbook Air with M1 Chip?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, nasm, apple-m1

I have a course on assembly programming and `x86 NASM` is what they are following for the course.

For the online evaluation I have to make the following commands work on my computer to execute my `.asm` file on the terminal.

```sh
nasm -f elf file_name.asm
ld -melf_i386 file_name.o -o file_name 
./file_name
```

I have installed [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/) and followed the instructions given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XFNUeWhsIQ) to set up my virtual machine on my **2020 M1 Macbook Air**.

After installing `NASM` and trying to run a file called `file_name.asm` using the commands mentioned above I get the following response.

```
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386
Supported emulations: aarch64linux aarch64elf aarch64elf32 aarch64elf32b aarch64elfb armelf armelfb aarch64linuxb aarch64linux32 aarch64linux32b armelfb_linux_eabi armelf_linux_eabi
```

I understand that this has something to do with the chip compatibly and might work if I changed `elf_i386` to anything even in the error response, with slight variations.

I also understand `NASM` can be run natively on `MAC OS` with slight variations of the same without using a Virtual Machine, But the requirements of my course is that I should be running `NASM` on Linux with and I should be using the above mentioned commands to run the `.asm.` file.

I have been stuck on this for a few days and would be grateful if anyone can help me with this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Here is the the output of entering `lscpu` into the terminal for reference of my cpu architecture on the Virtual Machine.

```
Architecture:                    aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):                  64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       0x00
Model:                           0
Stepping:                        0x0
BogoMIPS:                        48.00
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Vulnerable
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Not affected
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm jscvt fcma lrcpc dcpop sha3 asimddp sh
                                 a512 asimdfhm dit uscat ilrcpc flagm sb dcpodp flagm2 frint
```